# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

This crash report on the console in code I have recycler views more than one activity.
all the recycler views are added in the main thread. the code was tested and debugged but the reporting crash didn't occur. using   `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1`.

###### Crash

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition (RecyclerView.java:117)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:49)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline (GapWorker.java:14)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline (GapWorker.java:15)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline (GapWorker.java:22)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch (GapWorker.java:3)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run (GapWorker.java:70)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:236)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8019)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:600)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Play console is showing me this crash for Samsung devices. Same stack trace. Also doesn't show any actual code from my app, so it's  hard to reproduce.